# Cannot generate WCF client class with "reusing types from referenced assemblies" option

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2013

I have all service contracts and data contracts in a separate class library project so that it could be referenced by both the WCF project and the WPF project:
[image: projects]

When adding a service reference to the WCF service, I did configure Visual Studio to reuse all referenced assemblies, which includes the Contract project:
[image: reuse]

The generation process fails with warnings and errors:
[image: errors]

```
Warning 1   The 'bindingConfiguration' attribute is invalid - The value 'BasicHttpBinding_IDataService' is invalid according to its datatype 'serviceBindingConfigurationType' - The Enumeration constraint failed. C:\..\App\App.Workflow\App.config   16  39  App.Workflow
Warning 2   The 'contract' attribute is invalid - The value 'IDataService' is invalid according to its datatype 'clientContractType' - The Enumeration constraint failed.   C:\..\App\App.Workflow\App.config   16  80  App.Workflow
Error   3   Custom tool error: 'Reference.cs' : An assembly with the same simple name '.. Contract, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null has already been imported. Try removing one of the references or sign them to enable side-by-side.    C:\..\App\App.Workflow\Service References\DataServiceReference\Reference.svcmap 1   1   App.Workflow
```

What is the correct way to generate a client class that will re-use types defined in the class library rather than re-generated ones?

---

UPDATE

My config file:
[image: config]

Workflow app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 

       <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />       

    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDataService" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:54519/DataService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IDataService" contract="IDataService"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IDataService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: 2 of the errors are pointing to app.config. Can you show it?
Try to check your app.contract.dll with "reuse types in specified ,,," too

Comment: sure. I have updated my question with screenshot of the app.config file.

Comment: As @Capitan says it seems there are errors in your configs. Could you add the whole content? Or at least the system.serviceModel-node.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

> contract="IDataService"name="BasicHttpBinding_IDataService"

to

> contract ="App.Contract.IDataService"
>   name="BasicHttpBinding_contract". –